# Replace carriage return in an email

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I'm trying to replace carriage returns with a line break in PHP so that my site moderators don't have to type 
 every time they want to add a new line when typing an email from my site. I've tried several different methods to replace the line breaks but none have worked. The methods that I have tried are:

```
preg_replace('/\r\n?/', "<br />", $str);
eregi_replace(char(13), "<br />", $str);
str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $str);
str_replace("\n", "<br />", $str);
```

and the nl2br function.

I've looked for the answer on Google for about half an hour and haven't found anything. Can anyone help?

Comment: `nl2br` should have worked, there must be another problem somewhere.

Comment: Did you just write those lines or did you set $str equal to it, too?
$str = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $str);
or 
$str = nl2br($str);

Comment: I wrote them like this: $str = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $str);

Comment: `ereg_*` and `eregi_*` functions are deprecated. Don't use them!

Answer (score 2):

Quite good example from php.net [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you test it like this?

```
$str = str_replace( "\r\n", "<br />", $str );
$str = str_replace( "\r", "<br />", $str );
$str = str_replace( "\n", "<br />", $str );
```

This should work pretty much always. And remember always use `"\r"` instead of `'\r'`.

Comment: Careful, you might end up replacing Windows line endings `"\r\n"` with two `<br />` tags here.

Comment: Thanx, altered the script, to check for doubles first.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is escaping your `r` and `n`.

Instead of

```
preg_replace('/\r\n?/', "<br />", $str);
```

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/\\r\\n/', "<br />", $str);
```